# Why am I getting a "resource not found" error for my Cloudinary videos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

Is there any settings on Cloudinary for video expiration?
I am facing an issue with the videos I uploaded to Cloudinary. Previously the videos were playing but now it doesn't play.
I have checked the links for Cloudinary and when I paste it in the browser it shows a "resource not found" error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see they exist on your media library?